# MongoDB - form one query with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

If doc has `isBasic: true`  - document must be returned only if `name: 'Patric'`.
If doc has `isBasic: false` - return document

Example doc:

```
{
  isBasic: <boolean>,
  name: <string>
}
```

It's something like

```
db.collection.find({
  {$if: {isBasic: true}, {name: 'Patric'}}
)
```

Comment: `db.collection.find` method [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html#examples) shows how to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good start by forming the syntax. I recommend you to look at documentation and try it out.

This can be solved by thinking another way.

`(A and B)  OR C`

You need to use $and and $or of mongodb.

```
db.collection.find({$or :[{
  $and : [
  {isBasic: true}, {name: 'Patric'}]}, 
  {is Basic :false} 
)
```